# Django Serving XLSX file for download via HttpResponse

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue serving a xlsx file via django api. I am able to download the file, but trying to open it leads to an error saying it is corrupted. I can open the file locally just cannot download it an open.

```
    response = HttpResponse(open(path, 'rb').read())
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=ProviderList.csv'
    return response
```

Comment: isnt that the content-type?

Comment: yes both regfer to same thing.

Comment: I tried your code with Django==2.1.7 and it's working fine (although I think the Content-Type should be application/vnd.open...).
Can you specify which version you are using?

Comment: (2, 1, 3, 'final', 0).

Comment: i see what you mean. I fixed it. still doesn't work. it works with CSVs just not XLSXs